# Usage of angular.equals()

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of numbers. I want to covert the elements to strings and compare those values with the input value (a string) and set the flag value accordingly as follows

```
function(id)
{
var arrayNum = [1,2,3];
var flag = true;

for(var i=0 ; i< i < arrayNum.length; i++)
{
 flag = angular.equals(id, arrayNum[i].toString())

if (flag == true){
//some output
}
else
{
//some output
}
} 


}
```

when I use arrayNum[i].toString() inside angular.equals() output is incorrect. But if i hardcode a value as follows

```
angular.equals(id,"2")
```

and if my input value is also 2 then output is correct. What is wrong in the way that i am trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than using angular.equals() I used the following method which works correctly.

```
function(id)
{
var arrayNum = [1,2,3];
var flag = true;

for(var i=0 ; i< i < arrayNum.length; i++)
{
 if(parseInt(id) == arrayNum[i])
{
 //some output
}

else
{
//some output
}
} 


}
```